# Using purrr to apply filter and mutate based on another data set

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I am trying to use `purrr` to apply filter *and* mutate a variable, both based on values of another data frame.

```
# This is the original table
set.seed(100)
dfOriginal <- data.table(age = sample(10:60, 10))

# Following is the second data frame containing one variable which 
# I would like to filter by - age criterion
# and then to mutate with - age band
dfAgeBands <- data.table(ageCriterion = c("age > 0 & age <= 20", "age > 20 & age <= 30"),
              ageBand = c("Young Adults", "Adults"))

finalDf <- map2(dfAgeBands$ageCriterion, dfAgeBands$ageBand, function(x,y){dfOriginal[.x, ageBands := .y]})
```

Edit: Just corrected the code (which was built for a different dataset!)
But it still does not work.

The expected output would be like the below, as per the rules defined by `ageCriterion` in the `dfAgeBands` dataframe.

```
    age      ageBand
 1:  56         <NA>
 2:  51         <NA>
 3:  41         <NA>
 4:  36         <NA>
 5:  44         <NA>
 6:  32         <NA>
 7:  19 Young Adults
 8:  53         <NA>
 9:  28       Adults
10:  29       Adults
```

Comment: Would be great if you showed us expected output.

Comment: I guess you need `for(i in seq_len(nrow(dfAgeBands))) dfOriginal[eval(parse(text = dfAgeBands$ageCriterion[i])), ageBand := dfAgeBands$ageBand[i]]`

Comment: @akrun to the rescue, as usual :) But would be great if you have time for a `purrr` solution too! Once you post it, I can check that as an answer

Comment: If this data is coming from an external source then I very strongly urge you **not** to use `eval(parse(…))`. It’s a huge security hole. And there may not be a scenario *today* in which this can be exploited. But what about tomorrow? This is how most security breaches happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better not to go through `eval(parse` usually, but the expression here is tempting to use that.  One option is to `eval`uate the expression in the `i` by looping through each element of 'ageCriterion' and assign (`:=`) the 'ageBand' value to those that satisfy the condition in `i`

```
library(data.table)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(dfAgeBands)))  {

   dfOriginal[eval(parse(text = dfAgeBands$ageCriterion[i])), 
           ageBand := dfAgeBands$ageBand[i]]
  }

dfOriginal[]
```

---

Or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
pwalk(dfAgeBands, ~ dfOriginal[eval(parse(text = .x)), ageBand := .y])
dfOriginal[]
#    age      ageBand
# 1:  25       Adults
# 2:  22       Adults
# 3:  37         <NA>
# 4:  12 Young Adults
# 5:  32         <NA>
# 6:  56         <NA>
# 7:  46         <NA>
# 8:  26       Adults
# 9:  33         <NA>
#10:  17 Young Adults
```

Answer (score 2):

solution using a non-equi join from `data.table`..

first, get the min and max age per group, extract from description

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
#get minimum and maximum age grom group
dfAgebands <- dfAgeBands %>% mutate( minAge = stringr::str_extract( ageCriterion, "(?<=\\> )[0-9]+(?= &)") %>% as.numeric(),
                                     maxAge = stringr::str_extract( ageCriterion, "(?<=\\<= )[0-9]+(?=$)") %>% as.numeric() )
```

> ```
>           ageCriterion      ageBand minAge maxAge
> 1  age > 0 & age <= 20 Young Adults      0     20
> 2 age > 20 & age <= 30       Adults     20     30
> ```

now, you can easily perform a non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
dfOriginal[ dfAgebands, ageBand := i.ageBand, on = c("age > minAge", "age <= maxAge")]

#     age      ageBand
#  1:  55         <NA>
#  2:  40         <NA>
#  3:  41         <NA>
#  4:  33         <NA>
#  5:  56         <NA>
#  6:  25       Adults
#  7:  11 Young Adults
#  8:  13 Young Adults
#  9:  28       Adults
# 10:  27       Adults
```

Comment: very interesting! Thank you for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth --- i.e., my solution in addition to the solution of giants like akrun and other geniuses like Wimpel ---  here is a solution with map2:

```
map2(ageBands$AgeCriteria, ageBands$AgeBand, 
          function(x,y){df1[eval(parse_expr(x)), ageBands := y]})
```